# How to deploy xap file on unregistered windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have developed one windows phone 8 application. I have tested the app in my registered windows phone 8 (Nokia Lumia 520) and it is working fine. Now I have decided to test the app in my unregistered windows phone 8.

As you already know for testing the app, we need XAP file. So I have build the app in visual studio 2012 by right click on the project and select build option.Then XAP file is generated in the BIN folder of the application.

Now I have copied the XAP file to the SD Card 's root folder on my windows phone. After that I have restarted my windows phone. Now I click on the Start and then Store in my phone. Now it has to show SD Card option. But I didn't get this option.

So to check this again, I have downloaded the application(XAP file) from windows store.Now I have copied the XAP file to the SD Card 's root folder on my windows phone. After that I have restarted my windows phone. Now I click on the Start and then Store in my phone. Now the SD Card option is visible. But there is only one XAP file (which I downloaded from the store) is visible and the one which I have developed is not visible.

I don't know what is the problem in my XAP file. Please provide the solution as early as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't side load an app on unregistered device.

You can post your app on marketplace for beta testing distribution. It's described here: [Beta testing your app and in-app products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I registered my mobile @ DevCenter & copy xap file onto device sd card,but it is not showing in sd card options at store.

Comment: You should use USB cable and VS.

Comment: Actually I want to give my xap file to other person who doesn't have VS installed.He just take xap file & copy to sd card & install on device.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Is their certificate required for creating xap file,because when I copy xap file on sd card,it's not showing xap file on sd card.Is it we have to give target OS for application,in my app target OS is WP OS7.1